# JFreeChart - mark a border between stacked bar components

Tags: jfreechart

I am using jfreechart stacked bar and instead of colors I would like only to mark the borders between the components with a black line . is that possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have two series, set `DrawBarOutline` to true and then set the `SeriesOutlinePaint`

```
StackedXYBarRenderer renderer = new StackedXYBarRenderer(0.10);
renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.BLACK);
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, Color.BLACK);
```